# Is it OK for someone to follow their family's rented moving truck into a weigh station?

Tags: legal, driving, rental

My wife and I will be moving from Florida to Texas in a few weeks. I will be driving a 16ft Penske truck with a tow dolly carrying one of our cars, and my wife will be following me in our other car.

As far as I know, I need to pull in to any open weigh stations. However, I'm not sure if it would be alright for my wife to follow me in. I'd like to do that to avoid making her slow down or wait on the shoulder for me to catch up. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about the weigh station? I am trying to find a reference for you, but I think weight stations only apply for commercial traffic above a certain tonnage.

Comment: I had a longer penske truck towing a car traveling from Ohio to California through Texas. I was told to not enter the weigh stations. But we've had this question before...

Comment: @BurhanKhalid [It depends on the state](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38875). In many states you will can expect simply to be waved through, but you are still expected to make the effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem with your wife following you in. It is normal when families are renting trucks and the weight inspectors and state troopers are well aware of it.

The good news is the process is simple - just roll over a road, follow the stop sign and be on your way.

You might be asked (should you be over the weight) if you are carrying household goods/personal items and then be politely nodded along.

From my experience, Texas is especially strict about weight stations - but your mileage may vary :) depending on the inspector on duty.

Good luck and have a safe trip!