# Transporting horses interstate DOT

Tags: usa, transportation, arizona, animal-riding, south-dakota

If I am hauling my horses from SD to AZ in a Semi truck with DOT licensed agriculture, do I need to get permits and stop at every weigh station?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Scales and inspection stations are operated by the states, and you would need to look up the regulation for each state you will be driving through. This question has come up before in the context of moving trucks, e.g. *[Vehicles required/allowed in weigh stations on US interstates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38875)*.

Comment: Some states may also check the horses’ paperwork (vet inspection, coggins, ...)